# Installing Eclipse 4.5 on ARM Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse, arm

I recently got an excellent deal on a Chromebook (Hisense C11), and have used crouton to install Trusty Tahr (14.04):

```
(trusty)craig@localhost:~$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 20 20:48:35 PDT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

(trusty)craig@localhost:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

I installed JDK 1.8 (ARM) from Oracle, which is working great.

I then used the package manager to install the generic `eclipse` package, as Eclipse doesn't seem to provide ARM builds of their standard IDE packages.

However, to my dismay, the `trusty` repository only contains Eclipse 3.8, which doesn't have support for JDK 8.

How can I install Eclipse 4.5 (or any version with Java 8 support, really) in Ubuntu on ARM? I'm fine compiling if necessary, but it seems since 99% of this should be `.jar`-based, I figure I'm just looking for a newer version of the executable?

**Edit:** I would also be satisfied with the ability to get my *current* Eclipse 3.8 installation working with Java 8, but that seems harder.

Comment: Do you encounter any problems when following the steps described in the article [How to Install The Latest Eclipse Release in Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/) ?

Comment: @harrymc Eclipse no longer offers ARM builds - so downloading it straight from their website is not an option.

Comment: I don't believe that what you are asking for is possible. Basically, you are seeking to create your own binary release of Eclipse 4.5 on ARM Ubuntu. However, instructions or a script to compile Eclipse are not made available by the Eclipse developers, and even if recompiled it might still not work because of the need to supply some platform-dependent code.

Comment: @harrymc Sure, but _somebody_ did it for Eclipse 3.8 in the `trusty` repository, I'm just trying to figure out how. Did ARM previously have first-class support, which has since been dropped? Or was it a one-off build in the first place? How _does_ Eclipse get built for Windows? Surely there's a build script somewhere, it can't be some solo guy hiding in the shadows. :-)

Comment: Oh yes, it can be one ARM developer in charge of making ARM releases, who may have left the project or is now otherwise occupied for personal reasons. You might ask to be put in contact with him on the Eclipse forums, which probably means that you will be joining the project. But be warned that this risks taking up much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Eclipse has some platform dependent code even though written in Java. Simply downloading the binary build will not work. Your only option may be compiling it.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307253/why-is-eclipse-platform-dependent

Comment: How is that an answer?